# Performance difference between connection mode and connection less unix domain sendmsg()

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, datagram, packets

I'm writing an application which involves passing file descriptors between two processes. I'm using unix domain sockets' `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()` to do the same by passing FDs as ancillary data.

What I found in my tests is that the performance of `sendmsg()` for connection-mode `SOCK_SEQPACKET` sockets is way better than that of connection-less `SOCK_DGRAM` sockets. What is the reason behind this?

This is how I'm testing my code. The client side program is an event loop using `epoll`, which does a `recvmsg()` on the FD and the immediately closes the received FDs, pretty straight forward.

On the server side, I have multiple threads doing `sendmsg()` to this single FD on the client side. I've tried multiple combinations of no of threads, no of `sendmsg()` calls per thread etc, but the `sendmsg()` for connection-mode sockets is way faster than it's connection-less socket counter part.

Only reason I can think of is that kernel might have to be doing a lookup for client FD by socket path name which involves some file system calls?

Comment: What are you trying to measure, file-descriptor passing speed? How? Where are your trace points? Just around `sendmsg` calls?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `gettimeofday()` around `sendmsg()` calls to calculate total time spent for these calls.

Comment: Measure time from sender to receiver instead - I bet they would be comparable between stream and datagrams. My (unconfirmed) theory is that streaming calls just copy data to the kernel for later handoff to the other side, while datagram calls block until other side receives the messages.

Comment: I'm comparing between `SOCK_SEQPACKET` and `SOCK_DGRAM`. I need to have message based transfer as I'm passing file descriptors, so there are no streaming sockets here. Sockets on both sides are non-blocking. I was of the opinion that `sendmsg()` returns as soon as data is transferred to receiving side's buffer, even if `recvmsg()` call is not made yet.

Comment: Same, measure time from sender to receiver, not around the syscalls.

Comment: What's a reliable way to do that? I can pass a unique id from sender to receiver to identify one complete transfer, but I'm not sure how to calculate total time. Or are you suggesting that I calculate the total time spent for sending and receiving calculated separately in client and server processes?

Comment: Have the sender timestamp the message (you'll need additional space in the message for that), do a diff on the receiver.